# How to prove that all powers of two minus one have only 1's when in binary representation?

Tags: proof-writing, binary

It just came to my mind that all powers of two, when represented in binary format, are composed of only 1's, not 0's. I can see some logic behind it, however I can't seem to come up with an actual proof of that.

```
1: 1

3: 11

7: 111

15: 1111

31: 11111
```

Comment: $2^n-1=1+2+2^2+\dots+2^{n-1}$.

Comment: x^n-1=(x-1)(x^(n-1)+x^(n-2)+x^(n-3)…+x+1)

Comment: Compare: all powers of ten minus one, when represented in decimal format, are composed of only 9's, not 0's, not 1's, ..., not 8's.